# is it possible to use RBF sampler to construct kernel and use it for prediction at new data point?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, kernel-trick, rbf-kernel

I would like to construct a kernel from very large samples which makes it impossible to construct the N by N kernel matrix. I can use RBF sampler (random fourier features) to make the dimension more manageble e.g. 1000 features. my goal is to use kernel regression to make prediction for new data points? I know how to do it with N by N kernel which is out of the question due to the size, just want to know if there is a way to predict new X with kernel built from sampled random features?